# DocuSign OAuth Token Generator Broken?

Tags: docusignapi

I am prototyping a DocuSign integration, going through one of their walkthroughs.

It says to visit their OAuth Token Generator, for testing: https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/code-example-embedded-signing

But... that page just loads forever. Clicking into the inspector, I see an error for `/oauth-token-generator/oauth/token`

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Is their OAuth Token Generator broken? Or, is there something else I can do to generate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to open a new incognito window, or clear your browser cookies or use a different browser.

Comment: New incognito window it was!